# angularJs ivh-treeView search filter bug

Tags: angularjs, filter, treeview

ivt.treeView filter is not filtering property, eg. if you type a letter "a" or "e" in the search (filter) box, it doesn't filter anything, it shows as if you have not typed anything in the search.

I tested this in my local and on the sites jsbin using their filter demo link.
Is this a bug? Anyidea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not the filter is working as expected. Please see [the filtering docs](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#filtering) on ivhTreeview's README. The value you provide to `ivh-treeview-filter` is passed through to Angular's own `filterFilter`; `filterFilter` checks against **every** property of the objects its filtering, it also converts boolean property values to strings `'true'` and `'false'`.

Nodes in the tree track their selected state with a boolean property, e.g. `selected: false`. If you enter an "a" or "e" as your filter string everything with `selected: false` will remain in the case of "a" and the filter will truly do nothing in the case of "e" since the letter shows up on both `'true'` and `'false'`.

The good news is `filterFilter` lets you have some control over what properties should be considered when filtering (see the options for `expression` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)).

E.g. if you want to only consider node labels when filtering, and those labels are stored in a property called `myLabel` you could do something like this:

```
<div ivh-treeview="fancy.bag"
     ivh-treeview-filter="{myLabel: fancy.myFilterString}">
</div>
```

You can also provide your own filtering function.